# Python SQLite3 Binding error when using variable

Tags: python, sqlite

I have imported uuid and used it to randomly generate a 32 digit UserID, and at first it would work fine and register the user, but when I attempted to try and first check the database incase the UserID has already been used, I get a binding error, and can't figure out whats wrong with it.

```
var_usertype = ("Teacher")
        Firstname = var_FName.get()
        Surname = var_SName.get()
        Password = var_password1.get()
        username = Firstname[0:3] + Surname
        conn = sqlite3.connect('MyComputerScience.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        UserID = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-','')
        var_insert = (UserID, Firstname, Surname, Password, username, var_usertype)
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserID = ?", (UserID))
        data = c.fetchall()
        if len(data) == 0:
            c.execute('insert INTO users (UserID, FName, SName, password, username, userType)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?);', var_insert)
            Label(screen2, text = "Successfully registered! Your username to log in is "+username+"", fg = "GREEN", font = "Calibri").pack()
            Main.login()



c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserID = ?", (UserID))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 32 supplied.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserID = ?", (UserID))
```

This is a very common beginner mistake. The second argument is supposed to be a tuple, list or other similar thing. In this case, you're passing it a string, and each character is treated as an individual value that should be bound.

You want:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserID = ?", (UserID,))
```

Note the trailing comma to make the argument a one-element tuple.